# Got this on Sequelize hook initialization

Tags: typescript

Hi there I'm using an app typescript node js

and in deploy to heroku I got this error

node_modules/sequelize-typescript/dist/hooks/shared/hook-meta.d.ts:2:32 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'sequelize/types/lib/hooks'.

```
   2 import { SequelizeHooks } from "sequelize/types/lib/hooks";
```

My package.json is

```
    "dependencies": {
        "bcrypt": "^3.0.2",
        "bluebird": "^3.5.1",
        "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
        "dotenv": "^6.2.0",
        "express": "^4.16.2",
        "express-statsd": "^0.3.0",
        "express-validator": "^5.3.0",
        "hashids": "^1.2.2",
        "jsonwebtoken": "^8.4.0",
        "mailgun-js": "^0.22.0",
        "mysql2": "^1.5.1",
        "nyc": "^13.1.0",
        "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.10",
        "sequelize": "^4.37.5",
        "sequelize-typescript": "^1.0.0-alpha.1",
        "strong-error-handler": "^2.3.0",
        "supertest": "^3.3.0",
        "uuid": "^3.3.2"   },  
 "devDependencies": {
        "@types/express": "^4.0.39",
        "@types/mocha": "2.2.41",
        "@types/node": "^8.10.39",
        "mocha": "^5.2.0",
        "ts-node": "^3.3.0",
        "tslint": "^5.8.0",
        "typescript": "^2.8.1"   }
```

Comment: The error states that it cannot find "sequelize/types/lib/hooks" so I suggest you check if you have your path correct. If yes you may try to reinstall that module.

Comment: I there thanks by the reply... I already made a rm -r node_modules and lock file.
And install from scratch..
But the error keeps going...
Thanks

Comment: `"sequelize/types/lib/hooks"` Does this point to a directory or to a file? If it points to a file. Could you show the content of it?

Comment: its installed with sequelize ...

Comment: Any solution here?  I'm running into the same issue.